# Cannot launch URL in system browser in Cordova iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

I am developing two apps in Cordova for iOS using the iOS 6.3.0 platform and WKWebView. On the "about" page of the apps, I include a few acknowledgements with web links and a link to my website. One app launches the URL's in the system browser with no special formatting, custom targets, etc. - this is the desired behavior. The links are set like so:

```
<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
```

And the console output in Xcode looks like this:

```
2023-05-04 16:16:16.768103-0400 TheLakeEffect[6745:3916856] CDVWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView::
2023-05-04 16:16:16.768151-0400 TheLakeEffect[6745:3916856] CDVWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView title: The Lake Effect
```

The other app, using the same platform stack and nearly the same HTML/JS code, loads the URL's into the app's internal web view, with no way to get back to the app pages. The call to [CDVWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView] never fires.

I cannot account for the differences in behavior here.

I have not been able to get the InAppBrowser plugin to work, but I would rather not use it anyway - it is full of deprecated code that may be rejected by Apple. I simply want the same behavior as in the other app. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It was a stray  in the config.xml file that was in the staging folder of Cordova/iOS. Odd how a single line can cause so much frustration.